# (.net) pictureBox show image from RAM

Tags: .net, c++-cli, picturebox

I need to show an Image from RAM in the pictureBox. I spend my whole day yesterday to try and get it work. Here is a bit of code to show you how I am currently trying to do it, but I cannot get the System::Drawing::Bitmap to work. All I get is an empty pictureBox.
I also write a BMP file to my disk and the file is just as intended (greyscale noise). I would be very happy if you could help me out!

```
unsigned char* imgData;
imgData = (unsigned char*)malloc(100 * 100 * sizeof(unsigned char)*3);
for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100; i++){
     memset(imgData+ i*3,rand()%255, 3); //generates a random pixel vaoue between 0 and 255 and then assigns all three colors of a pixel to it
}
// this->textBox1->Text += "Values: " + *(imgData + 1) + " \r\n";
 const char* fname;
 fname = "test.bmp";
 write_bmp(fname, 100, 100, (char*)imgData); //writes 24-bit BMP File

 System::Drawing::Bitmap ^mybm = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(
           100, 100, 100*sizeof(unsigned char)*3,
           System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
           (System::IntPtr) imgData);

 this->pictureBox1->Image = mybm;
 this->pictureBox1->Show();

 free(imgData);
```

Comment: I think that stride parameter should be `100*sizeof(unsigned char)*3`

Comment: For testing purposes, create `Bitmap` from the file `test.bmp`, what result do you have?

Comment: stride parameter has been adjusted, but pictureBox still shown no image. The bmd file on HDD can be opened using any image editing program.
I am relatively new to c++ and I can not get the create bitmal from file suggestion to work:
System::Drawing::Bitmap ^fromFile = gcnew System::Drawing::Image::FromFile("test.bmp");
I get "expected a type identifier"

Comment: Don't use `gcnew` for that; `System::Drawing::Image::FromFile` is a static function, not a type.

Comment: The code that I showed above is part of a button click event which means that with every pressing of the button a new image is generated. If I load the image with      System::Drawing::Image ^fromFile = System::Drawing::Bitmap::FromFile("test.bmp");

it is correctly displayed in the pictureBox, but will not be updatedif I press the button.
However, saving the image and then reading it from HDD is not what I am looking for here because I do not want to save every image before being able to view it (the program will be working with hundrets of images in RAM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN topic `Bitmap Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)`:

The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, **the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.**

In your case, you release `imgData` array immediately after `Bitmap` creating. Keep this array persistent all time when `Bitmap` is alive, according to the constructor requirements.

Comment: thank you very much that fixed it! How should I free the memory again? If I do it within the button_click event then the picture is not shown anymore but I cannot free it outside because I declared the imgdata points within the event

Comment: Well, declare imgdata outside the function, as class member.